# Is it possible to use SymmetricDS with the Room Persistence Library?

Tags: android, android-room, symmetricds

I am trying to build an android application that synchronises its SQLite database  automatically with a remote database with SymmetricDS http://www.symmetricds.org. I would like to use the Room persistence library https://developer.android.com/topic/libr… instead of SQLiteOpenhelper to access and manage my SQLite database on the client device but could not find any examples to set up SymmetricDS and Room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. SymmetricDS also uses the interface in the android.database.sqlite namespace, 
so SQLiteOpenhelper too. However, you can modify the SymmetricDs Android plugin source code available at [github](https://github.com/JumpMind/symmetric-ds/tree/3.9/symmetric-android) and change Android namespace for Room interfaces.

Comment: Hi, could you be more specific please ? Have you done it yourself ?